# Approximation by sine polynomials

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the segment $[0,\pi]$
such that $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$.
Prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a sine polynomial
$$
P(x)= \sum_{k=1}^n b_k\sin(kx)
$$ 
such that
$$
\sup_{0 \leq x \leq \pi}  \big|f(x)-P(x)\big|\le \epsilon.
$$

Well , Stone-Weierestrass theorem says that if $X$ is compact Hausdorff and if $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of continuous real-valued functions which separates points in X and contains $1$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $X$. 
I can show why the set of all sine polynomials form an algebra and that they separate points. This algebra does not contain constant functions, and maybe in this problem we do not need this condition due to the fact that $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$ . but I do not see how to show this rigorously.

I would appreciate any hints/suggestions.

Comment: This concept is the foundation of [Fourier analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis).

Answer (score 1):

Let's throw the constant functions in, so that  the Stone-Weierstrass theorem applies. So, there exist integer $n$ and coefficients $b_0,\dots,b_n$ such that
$$\sup_{x\in [0,\pi]}\left|f(x) - b_0-\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \sin kx\right|\le \epsilon \tag{1}$$
In particular, (1) holds when $x=0$. What does this say about $b_0$? Conclude that
$$\sup_{x\in [0,\pi]}\left|f(x) - \sum_{k=1}^n b_k \sin kx\right|\le 2\epsilon \tag{2}$$